# How to delete local ssh tunnel

Tags: git, ssh, localhost, gitlab, ssh-tunnel

I have a problem with my ssh tunnel on my Macbook.
I accidentally hit enter on this command: `ssh -f -N [REMOTE_IP]`.

Now when I want to connect with dat REMOTE_IP, what always worked, I got a timeout request: `ssh: connect to host gitlab.com port [PORT_OF_REMOTE]: Operation timed out`.

Background: I have set my ~/.ssh/config with the Host to the gitlab.com hostname:

`Host [REMOTE_IP]
  HostName gitlab.com
  Port [PORT_OF_REMOTE]
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Now did I some research the past few hours to find out how to delete this local ssh tunnel. I know the syntax of the command is not right, so the tunnel never could be created, because I missed some parameters. But it broke my ssh to connect with my remote server.

When I comment out the HostName gitlab.com rule, it works fine, but I need that rule to use git on my server.

or

Trying to kill the ssh process also didn't work with `ps -ax | grep ssh`.

EDIT: Tried to find the PID with `ps -ax | grep ssh` and kill it with `kill <PID>`, but the PID just changes every time I hit the ps -ax command.

Do you have any ideas how to fix this/ how to delete that local ssh tunnel?

Thanks

Comment: That's not how you kill a process. Try 'pkill -f ssh' or 'kill <PID>' using the PID of the ssh process.

Comment: @jdowner sorry, I did that, but my description was not clear enough. Also this command `pkill -f ssh` didn't work for me :(

Comment: Does restarting the computer help?

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to:

```
$ ssh -O exit [REMOTE_IP]
```

That close any existing connection.

Comment: I tried that, but also no success..

`[name]@MacBook-Pro ~ $ ssh -O exit [remote ip]`  
`No ControlPath specified for "-O" command`  
`[name]@MacBook-Pro ~ $ ssh -O exit [remote port]`  
`No ControlPath specified for "-O" command`

Comment: @Dennis try with a clean/empty  `~/.ssh/config`

Comment: yes that works, but the problem is, when I use the same content of that file to make a ssh connection with gitlab, the connection still can't made (time out).

Isn't there just a file or process or something I can kill, this is very annoying haha

Comment: @Dennis your configuration is trying to connect to gitlab, not your remote ip, in any case if no connection was made there should not be any process hanging around

Comment: you are right.. that was a dumb action from me.. I changed the values of the config and now I can connect again. The problem with gitlab permission denied is also fixed. I had to recreate a new private key. Everything works fine now. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The following command will find process with certain name and send kill signal to it,

```sh
pkill -f "ssh -f -N [REMOTE_IP]"
```

p.s. in my `~/.zshrc` (or `~/.bashrc`), I set such aliases to start or stop in one command. :)

```sh
alias server-up='ssh -fNTML 8888:localhost:8888 [REMOTE IP]'
alias server-down='pkill -f "ssh -fNTML 8888:localhost:8888 [REMOTE IP]"'
```

Reference: https://mpharrigan.com/2016/05/17/background-ssh.html